# How to get the colors of a bar plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, bar-chart

There are a number of similar questions out there, but I am struggling to tailor it to my specific case (which is in fact easier). I have the following data:

```
data = {'CCM1': {'Exact': 15.32, '1 Notch': 36.29, '2 Notches': 45.97},
    'CCM2': {'Exact': 24.19, '1 Notch': 42.74, '2 Notches': 54.03},
    'CCM3': {'Exact': 39.25, '1 Notch': 70.09, '2 Notches': 88.79},
    'CCM4': {'Exact': 29.03, '1 Notch': 65.32, '2 Notches': 88.71},
    'CCQ1': {'Exact': 17.74, '1 Notch': 41.40, '2 Notches': 54.84},
    'CCQ2': {'Exact': 25.27, '1 Notch': 50, '2 Notches': 64.52},
    'CCQ3': {'Exact': 29.57, '1 Notch': 67.74, '2 Notches': 89.25},
    'CCQ4': {'Exact': 31.18, '1 Notch': 67.74, '2 Notches': 88.71},
    'PCM1': {'Exact': 15.05, '1 Notch': 30.65, '2 Notches': 42.47},
    'PCM2': {'Exact': 15.05, '1 Notch': 28.49, '2 Notches': 42.47},
    'PCM3': {'Exact': 22.58, '1 Notch': 44.09, '2 Notches': 64.52},
    'PCM4': {'Exact': 40.32, '1 Notch': 68.28, '2 Notches': 84.95},
    'PCQ1': {'Exact': 12.37, '1 Notch': 26.34, '2 Notches': 32.36},
    'PCQ2': {'Exact': 11.83, '1 Notch': 29.57, '2 Notches': 46.24},
    'PCQ3': {'Exact': 34.41, '1 Notch': 64.52, '2 Notches': 86.02},}
```

Which I can plot using the code below

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = df.T
df ['sum'] = df.sum(axis=1)
x=df.sort_values('sum', ascending=False)[['Exact','1 Notch','2 Notches']].plot.bar() 
plt.axhline(y=31.75, color='blue', linestyle='--')
plt.axhline(y=76.19, color='orange', linestyle='--')
plt.axhline(y=90.48, color='green', linestyle='--')
```

which yields the following plot:
[image]

In reality, I would like the colours of the lines to assume the exact same colour as the barplots - i.e., the green line assumes the same shade of green as the green bar, the orange line assumes the same shade of orange as the orange bar and so on. However, since I do not know what colours have been used to generate the parplots, this is not possible. Some help here would be appreciated!

Comment: The default colors in matplotlib can be specified as 'C0', 'C1', etc. See https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/prev_whats_new/dflt_style_changes.html#id2

Comment: You can also give explicit colors as parameter to the bar plot: `my_colors = ['dodgerblue', 'crimson', 'limegreen']` and  `.....plot.bar(color=my_colors)`. And then use the same colors for the line plots. E.g. `for value, color in zip([31.75, 76.19, 90.48], my_colors): plt.axhline(y=value, linestyle='--')`.